# Error: Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, ubuntu-18.04, node-html-pdf

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Instance running Nginx and NodeJs project, I am trying to create a PDF using html-pdf library but Its giving me following issue.

```
Error: Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
```

I have tried all the possible solution available on the internet for eg.
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13433

Might be I am missing some step but In the end I am still stuck at generating PDF.

Thank you In Advance

Answer (score 3):

Please add these following using Octave-CLI

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

That resolved the issue for me.